# Loop through grouped pandas dataframe and perform some operations

Tags: pandas-groupby

I'm trying to perform an action on grouped data in Pandas. For each group based on variable "atable" and "column" I want to loop through the rows and see if sum of values for variable "value" for Include "Yes" is equal to sum of values for variable "value" for Include "No", only if Include has both "Yes" and "No" values for that group. If conditions are not met, then I want to print out the error with the row details. My data looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'atable':['Users','Users','Users','Users','Locks'],
    'column':['col_1','col_1','col_1','col_a','col'],
    'Include':['No','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes'],
    'value':[3,2,1,1,1],
})

df1


   Include  atable  column  value
0   No      Users   col_1    3
1   Yes     Users   col_1    2
2   Yes     Users   col_1    1
3   Yes     Users   col_a    1
4   Yes     Locks   col      1
```

I tried the below code but it is also erroring out for the rows which doesnot have either "Yes" or "No" in Include column as below:

```
grouped = df1.groupby(["atable", "column"])
for index, rows in grouped:
    if (([rows['Include'].isin(["Yes", "No"])])) and (rows[rows['Include'] == 'Yes']['value'].sum() != rows[rows['Include'] == 'No']["value"].sum()):
        print("error", index)

Output:
error ('Locks', 'col')
error ('Users', 'col_a')
```

I dont want my code to error out even for index 3 & 4 since those rows just has "Yes" in Include column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
grouped = df2.groupby(["atable", "column"])
for index, rows in grouped:
    if (rows[rows['Include'] == 'Yes']['value'].sum() != rows[rows['Include'] == 'No']["value"].sum()) and (rows[rows['Include'] == 'Yes']['value'].sum() != 0)  and (rows[rows['Include'] == 'No']['value'].sum() != 0):
        print("error", index)
```